# The flex behavior mentioned in the code below does not work well with border-box in MS edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The flex given in the  first div should have re sized the contents to fit the size. This behavior is correct in Chrome. Where as Edge does not behave in the same manner. I have read some posts mention flexbox does not work well with border-box. But in that case Chrome should have also behaved in the same manner as Edge.

```css
#notificationNameAnnex
{
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: calc(100% - 116px);
}
#markAsNotificationButtons
{
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #30b4f4;
    border: 1px solid #1a99d6;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:white;
}

*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerdiv
{
 width: 440px;
 height: 80px;  
 overflow: hidden; 
 border: 1px solid red; 
 background-color: #f9f3ff; 
 top: 0px; 
 font-family: roboto; 
 letter-spacing: 0.75px; 
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: column; 
}

.innerdiv
{
 width: 400px; 
 height: 65px;  
 position: relative; 
 padding: 6px; 
 padding-top: 3px; 
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: column; 
 justify-content: space-between; 
 background-color: #e5dbfd; 
 font-size: 10px; 
 color: #490181;
 border: 1px solid #d3c7ef; 
 border-radius: 3px; 
 margin: auto; 
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#notificationNameAnnex
{
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: calc(100% - 116px);
}
#markAsNotificationButtons
{
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #30b4f4;
    border: 1px solid #1a99d6;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:white;
}

*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerdiv
{
 width: 440px;
 height: 80px;  
 overflow: hidden; 
 border: 1px solid red; 
 background-color: #f9f3ff; 
 top: 0px; 
 font-family: roboto; 
 letter-spacing: 0.75px; 
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: column; 
}

.innerdiv
{
 width: 400px; 
 height: 65px;  
 position: relative; 
 padding: 6px; 
 padding-top: 3px; 
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: column; 
 justify-content: space-between; 
 background-color: #e5dbfd; 
 font-size: 10px; 
 color: #490181;
 border: 1px solid #d3c7ef; 
 border-radius: 3px; 
 margin: auto; 
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outerdiv">
        <div class="innerdiv" >
            <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;right: 5px;color: #9683bd;cursor: pointer;top:-5px;font-size:12px;" title="Close" >&Cross;</div>
            <div style="line-height: 12px;font-size: 10px;color:#490181;margin: auto;width: 360px;">
                This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px)This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px)
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;margin-top: 5px; ">
                <div style="width: 116px;font-size: 10px;font-weight:medium;height: 20px;">Give a name for feed</div>
                    <div id="notificationNameAnnex">
                        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;width: 210px;">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Give feed name" style="margin-bottom: 0;font-size: 11px;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="markAsNotificationButtons">
                            <div>Confirm</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="font-size: 10px; color: #818181; margin: auto; line-height: 20px; display: block;">
                Note: This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px).
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _But in that case chrome should have also behaved in the same manner as EDGE_ - that is incorrect. All browsers are different. Just because it works one way in one browser, it doesn't mean it should work exactly the same in another. It would be great if it worked like that, though.

Comment: I understand that. But how to get the behavior of chrome in EDGE is my question without altering the chrome output

Comment: can you make your code into an running snippet ? its hard to check all inline styles against the css to find the error.

Comment: The first you should do is to move all inline style to classes, as mixing them like this is recipe for disaster. Second, do us the favor and post a working code snippet reproducing the issue, to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Also, after a quick look, can't see a Flexbox issue, it appears to be a _height_ problem, as using fixed height like that kind of take away the efficiency of using Flexbox...still, with mixed inline/external can't say for sure. Btw, you should use `flex-basis` for height on flex column items.

Comment: I have edited the post and inserted the snippet. @LGSon Even if fixed height is given flex automatically resizes it. Atleast that is what I noticed in chrome. flex-basis is not a compulsory thing.

Comment: Found the reason...posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex item's by default won't be smaller than its content, as its `min-height` defaults to `auto`.

Chrome still shrink your sample, Firefox/Edge does not, and IMHO, it is Chrome that is wrong here.

The `innerdiv` is 65px high + 2px top margin, and its sibling, the bottom `div`, is about 20px (`line-height`), which make them about 87px high, and won't of course fit in its parent being 80px.

By adding `min-height: 0` to `innerdiv` solves the problem cross browser, allowing it to shrink.

Stack snippet

```css
#notificationNameAnnex {
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: calc(100% - 116px);
}

#markAsNotificationButtons {
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #30b4f4;
  border: 1px solid #1a99d6;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerdiv {
  width: 440px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #f9f3ff;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: roboto;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.innerdiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e5dbfd;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #490181;
  border: 1px solid #d3c7ef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
  min-height: 0;                 /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;right: 5px;color: #9683bd;cursor: pointer;top:-5px;font-size:12px;" title="Close">&Cross;</div>
    <div style="line-height: 12px;font-size: 10px;color:#490181;margin: auto;width: 360px;">
      This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px)This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px)
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex;margin-top: 5px; ">
      <div style="width: 116px;font-size: 10px;font-weight:medium;height: 20px;">Give a name for feed</div>
      <div id="notificationNameAnnex">
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;width: 210px;">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Give feed name" style="margin-bottom: 0;font-size: 11px;" />
        </div>
        <div id="markAsNotificationButtons">
          <div>Confirm</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size: 10px; color: #818181; margin: auto; line-height: 20px; display: block;">
    Note: This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px).
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro..This solved the problem. But I am not able to understand the logic. Is the problem with outer div or inner div ? In both the places flex is used

Comment: @JackDking It is the combo `dispay:flex` on outer and that its 2 children, the inner and bottom div, has a height that exceed the outer's height. In your case the inner div also happens to have `display:flex`, though in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think the problem here is height being mentioned for the first div and line-height being mentioned for the second. In general flex shrinks its children if it does not fit to the parent's size.

Comment: @JackDking The set height here, yes, in general, as I wrote in my answers first line, _Flex item's by default won't be smaller than its content, ...._.